# Using onMenuItemCLickListener from activity to call methods from multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, android-actionbar, items

i wish you all a good day.

First of all, sorry if i mispell frecuently because i din't know how to write on english, at least properly. But that's not a problem for all the response's that u can give me because i can read english pretty well (yeah, im a lazzy a.s.s. to learn it as should have to).

Second, im learning android right now and had been developing an app for like a month. The problem is that my app have an actionbar Menu on the Activity that contains 3 fragments THAT ARE ADDED BY a VIEWPAGER, so i can't cast them in activity to run their methods.... Thats a big problem!. Each one of those fragments have several EditText, and what i want is to USE MY ACTIVITY ACTIONBAR MENU ITEM CLICK to store all data from the EdtiText's and store it in an SQLite Database; one table per fragment.

I have been done everything and the only thing that i need isis to know how to call methods from the three fragments when pressing an item, on the onOptionClickListener OF THE MENU ITEM OF MY ACTIVITY.  (The most important thing is that is the menu of my activity, not the fragment's, and i cant instantate the fragments on my activity because im using viewpager to create them).

Sorry again of my mispell's, and sorry for not posting my code, but, is really large so instead of make it clear my problem im gonna confuse everbody, so its better that you can help me withow the need of my really large code, so thanks for understanding and helping me.

Comment: Add what code you have tried so far, what issues are you running into?

Answer (score 1):

There is a class for this.
Check Observer class.  actually is nothing too complicated.  You can easily remake this behave.

*just make a interface  with a method

```
 public interface MyObserverInterface {
     //the code that will run when a save button is clicked in your menu
     //fragment
     public void starAction();
 }
```

*make your fragments implament this interface.

*create a second class in wich you will get a reference to your fragments

```
public class MyObserver {

List<Fragment> listFragments;
//make sure your fragments implement the MyObserverInterface interface
public MyObserver(Fragment fragment1, Fragment fragment2) {
    listFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    listFragments.add(fragment1);
    listFragments.add(fragment2);
}

public void startActionInAllFragments(){
    for(int n=0;n<listFragments.size();n++){
        listFragments.get(n).starAction();
    }
}
}
```

Now just create an instance of MyObserver class in your fragment and call its method startActionInAllFragments()

let me know if it worked for u.

Comment: Thanks Helena. Im gonna try it right now, but i have a doubt.... Where i have to declare the interface? Sorry for  asking some too basic, but is the first approach that i have with interfaces, so i need to learn even the more basic stuff.

Comment: Thanks Helena. I be tried it, but din't work because even if i implements the interface on all fragments still din't recognizes the  ".startAction();" method.

Comment: you need to post your code,   so i can tell you where and how u most implement this class.
Also, you can check the Observer Class with Observable 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Observer.html

Comment: Thanks for all your help, i be solved this issue using interface's and passing data by it, instead of passing an event as i was trying to do before. Anyway, im in debt Helena with your good will, so thank you very much.